# how to Extract the contents of a pdf file into string variables

Tags: perl

I want to know how to do (a perl script) to extract the contents of a pdf and insert it into a database.

Example : I have a pdf file (see the example below : MyPdfFile), from this file I want to extract the item codes items (A and B), quantities (3 and 2) and prices (10 and 20) and insert them into a database (Table : ORDERS).

[MyPdfFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z179f.png)

thanks in advance for your helps.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: I have not done anything yet but I need advice, i need in the first step some helps like, what method to follow (steps of algorithm), which library to use and some links to help me to advance on this subject

Comment: try this moulde : https://metacpan.org/pod/CAM::PDF

Comment: Thanks to everyone else who replied to this post, i will try

Comment: @jsor: CAM::PDF is a good idea. If I wanted to solve this problem robustly, that is probably what I would try. However, I gather that OP prefers a solution with less fuss. His later remarks suggest that he probably does not know Perl well enough to manage CAM::PDF with reasonable effort. This is why I have instead suggested a quick-and-dirty hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly scanning, I see no existing Perl module that does exactly what you want with minimal fuss. However, on an open-source platform, [Poppler](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/poppler-utils) brings the utility `pdftotext`. Nothing prevents Perl from invoking the `pdftotext` binary via

```
my $output_of_pdftotext = `pdftotext $pdf_file`;
```

or

```
my @output_of_pdftotext = `pdftotext $pdf_file`;
```

If you do not mean to generalize your solution but just need something to solve your immediate problem (which, I assume, is your present orientation, insofar as you are using Perl, which excels at such usage), then my practical suggestion would be that you install Poppler's `pdftotext` utility, try it manually on your PDF, and see what it outputs. Then, given some minimal fluency in Perl, you can have your Perl script pattern-match the output and reformat it as you like.

**CHARACTER ENCODINGS**

Following up, OP asks:

> [T]o extract the contents of the pdf on the stdout poppler works great, but I have a small problem of the display of some words containing accents example: désignation (in pdf) = DÃ©signation in the standard output ?

The utf-8 character encoding encodes "é" with the two bytes C3 A9 (hexadecimal). The iso-8859-1 encoding encodes "Ã©" with the same two bytes. Your "désignation" is evidently encoded as utf-8, which is normal, so your standard output is right. However, apparently, your terminal wants to display iso-8859-1. If so, then your terminal is misinterpreting the standard output.

You could tell `pdftotext` to use iso-8859-1 (I leave it to you as an exercise to read the man page and figure out how to do this). However, my recommendation would be that you instead set your terminal to display utf-8.

How to set your terminal to display utf-8? This depends on which terminal you are using. I do not know your terminal. On my terminal, changing the encoding is easy. Perhaps a few minutes of exploration and experimentation with your terminal's preferences and settings will show you how to change to utf-8.

Comment: awesome. Thanks. First time using perl, to extract the contents of the pdf on the stdout poppler works great, but I have a small problem of the display of some words containing accents example: désignation (in pdf) = DÃ©signation in the standard output ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to answer your follow-up question. If you find the answer useful, then you can *upvote* it by marking the orange up arrow to the answer's left. If the answer is the best or only answer, then you can also *accept* it by marking the green check under the orange arrow. Answerers on Stack Overflow like arrows and checks because arrows and checks award answerers Reputation points on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the '-' after $pdf_file to capture the pdftext into $output_of_pdftotext. my $output_of_pdftotext = `pdftotext $pdf_file -`; Usage: pdftotext [options] [PDF-file] [text-file]